# How to number a string in each line of a file

Tags: bash, shell-script

Given file.txt that looks like this:

```
line_ some text
line_ some text
line_ some text
```

How can I number the lines like this with Bash:

```
line_1 some text
line_2 some text
line_3 some text
```

Here is my idea so far, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
var = 1
cat ./file.txt
while read line; do           
  sed "s/line_/line_(( var++ ))/"
done < ./file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk:

```
awk '$1=$1 FNR' <file>
```

`$1` is the first word of each record (line in this case). `FNR` is the input record number (line number in this case).

This command is replacing the `first word` of each line with the `first word + line-number` of each line.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. I just tried this. But it is not correct. What should I do differently?

    $ awk '$1=$1,FNR' <file.txt >file2.txt; cat file2.txt
    line_ some text
    line_ oaasdfa asdf
    line_ asdfasdf

Comment: @ScottE: new output is file2.txt

Comment: Apprantly I cannot format these comments correctly :)

Comment: This is pretty cool, I think. But can answer to the asker's complaint here?

Comment: @ScottE Your version of the code has an extra comma.   Remove that comma so that the code is identical to cuonglm's and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in perl:

```
perl -pe 'print "line_$.  $_";'  [file(s)]
```

If you want to send it to a file:

```
perl -pe 'print "line_$.  $_";'  [input_file] > [output_file]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. One tiny correction though in case anyone else references this; there was a missing ' after $_". So it should look like this:

perl -ne 'print "line_$. $_"' [input_file] > [output_file]

Comment: @ScottE, `line_ some text` -> `line_1 line_ some text`. Is it correct?

Comment: Actually, this would print an extra `line_`. Since you just want to add the line number after the first occurrence of an underscore, you can just use `perl -ne 's/_/$&$./' input_file  > output_file`

Comment: @JosephR., `-pe`. `-ne` prints nothing.

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin You're right. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're well covered here, but what the hell:

```sh
sed -et -e's/_ /\n/;P;=;D' <in | paste -'d_ ' - - -  >out
```

`sed`'s not exactly a whiz in the math department, but sometimes friends help it cheat, and so it gets by.

That transforms...

```
line_ some text
line_ some text
line_ some text
```

...to...

```
line_1 some text
line_2 some text
line_3 some text
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are quite new to Shell/Bash it seems, so for educational reasons, here is a solution for you, that covers your technology of choice (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

```
var=1
while read -r Line; do 
  printf "%s\n" "${Line/line_/line_$var}" >> ./file-new.txt
  let var++
done < ./file.txt
```